# After Big Sur upgrade, Android studio indicates NDK not installed but instead it alreay is

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-ndk, macos-big-sur

I have upgraded my mac to Big Sur. The project uses NDK and I have set the path as well on .bash_profile.
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle

After Big Sur upgrade, the below error:

Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: NDK is not installed

NDK is already installed and path is been set. Anything which is changed.Kindly refer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out if it is still ndk-bundle. In my case it was under `${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/*ndkversion*`

Comment: What does "it is still ndk-bundle" mean?